# Windows Active Directory Emulator

Tags: windows

Is there a LDAP server emulator or a Windows Active Directory emulator, I'm talking something in the lines of smtp4dev which doesn't have to be configured and just work for a development environment in order to test authentication code.

Comment: have a look at the discussion at http://serverfault.com/questions/185010 too

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suspect you might want to try [Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services (AD LDS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa705886(v=vs.85).aspx), formerly known as [Active Directory Application Mode (ADAM)](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=4201).